# sorty List by ASC or DESC

Tags: c#

Is it possible to sorty List by ASC or DESC?

```
private class CompAdvertisements : IComparer<Advertisements>
        {
            #region IComparer<Advertisements> Members

            public int Compare(Advertisements x, Advertisements y)
            {
                return x.Country.Name.CompareTo(y.Country.Name);
            }

            #endregion
        }
```

Comment: You have not accepted any answers given to your questions. Please accept answer, as this will give an indication of the correct ones...

Comment: ya, click the big tick under the vote count of the person's answer if its right.

Comment: thx i know how to accpet rate now. Thx again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two pretty straightforward choices: implement a `ReverseAdvertisementsComparer` class:

```
private class ReverseAdvertisementsComparer: IComparer<Advertisements>
{
    public int Compare(Advertisements x, Advertisements y)
    {
        // notice: reversed x and y
        return y.Country.Name.CompareTo(x.Country.Name);
    }
}
```

Or just call `List<Advertisements>.Sort()` followed by `List<Advertisements>.Reverse()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return y.Country.Name.CompareTo(x.Country.Name);
```

To reverse it